# Turning layered curves to polygon mesh?

Tags: 3d, mesh, polygon

I am confronted with the problem to render 3D representations for objects marked on microscope slices.
So I have a set of aligned polygons in parallel planes from tracing the outline of the object in the slices. I want to turn this into a 3d mesh of an approximate surface of the object.
The curves can have vastly different point density per curve length and overall number of points.

I know that there is not a unique solution, but I wonder if there is a fast algorithm to find A solution that looks reasonable.

Unfortunately, this also has to be solved in MATLAB. Not expecting MATLAB code of course, I just want to say that use function X in Y, Y not being MATLAB, is not extremely helpful.

Comment: Well, question, have you considering adapting the marching cubes algorithm to your specific use case?

Comment: You can look into the literature on [surface reconstruction from slices](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=surface+reconstruction+from+slices).

Comment: Tanks for the keywords, I will look into that.